# Boost Converter why is the calculation result not the same as simulation

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, boost

guys just asking why is my simulation result not the same as my calculation I am not sure why.

My design has the specification of Vin (power supply) = 1.5V , Vout = 5Volt with a Pout(power output of) = 1 watt , running on 10kHz frequency with 0.1V voltage ripple.

[image]
My calculation ^

[image]

My Schematic ^

[image]
The output voltage ^

Using the MOSFET Si7866DP
[image]

I am pretty sure that my calculation is correct but I am not sure why is my output not as my calculation. I did a few tests and I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with the mosfet(not sure if I am right). But can anyone tell me what's wrong and how do I fix it so that the output will be 5V instead of what I got?

Comment: "pulse 0 1.5V" won't turn the MOSFET on very hard. Try 4.5V pulses at which Rds is specified 2.6 mOhm.

Comment: Your formulas are wrong - it operates in DCM with an on time of 45 us, a discharge time of about 16 us and a dwell time of about 38 us. That's with my diode; yours isn't specified.

Comment: _"But due to forward voltage drop of the diode we have to see Vs as **Vin** - 0.7V"_ - this is wrong. Diode voltage drop subtracts from the _output_, not the input. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Oh I just that that is how I am supposed to calculate it, due to the fact that Vin to the load will ultimately be the Vsupply - 0.7V, So  just to clarify I should subtract 0.7V or add 0.7V from the Vout in my calculation?

Comment: The text says Vs is 1.5V - 0.7V = 0.8V. This is wrong. 0.7V should be added to the **output** voltage, ie. D = 1 - 1.5V/5.7V = 74%. In simulation (with corrected Gate drive) this ratio gives 5V output to the load when frequency is increased to 50kHz get continuous conduction.

Answer (score 3):

One issue I see with your design is that the gate of the mosfet is not being driven to a high enough voltage. You are driving the gate to 1.5 volts is not enough to turn it completely on so it will have a significant resistance which interferes with the charging of the inductor. Setting the mosfet gate to a higher voltage should fix this problem

Comment: Also add that using zero valued `trise/tfall` doesn't mean that there is no rise and fall time, they just default to `0.1*min(T, T-Ton)`. So in this case it's `0.1*(100u-84u)=0.1*16u=1.6u`, which not only it might not be what OP wants (large rise/fall transitions), but also increases Ton by `1.6u`, or `(trise+tfall)/2`.